# Why does repeatedly opening, appending and closing a text file cause the lines to be written in reverse order?

Tags: perl

Why does the following perl code:

```
for(open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt")){
    print $fh "one\n";
}
for(open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt")){
    print $fh "two\n";
}
for(open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt")){
    print $fh "three\n";
}
```

Write the following to test.txt?

```
three
two
one
```

Why is the order is getting reversed? My understanding is that each `for` block will automatically close the file when the block exits. Shouldn't this cause perl to flush any buffers before the the next block starts? I expected this code to open the file, write a line, close the file, then repeat all of those steps two more times. What am I missing?

I tested this with Perl 5.26.1, running on Ubuntu 18.04.3.

(Yes, I know I could easily get the lines to be written in the correct order by just putting all the `print` statements in the same block. That's not the question here. I want to understand *why* this behavior is happening.)

For bonus weirdness, when I run the following code:

```
for my $val (qw/ one two three /) {
    for(open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt")){
        print $fh "$val\n";
    }
}
```

It gives me the following output:

```
one
two
three
```

This code seems like it should be functionally identical to the previous code. Why is it behaving differently?

Comment: What do you expect?  The result is OS dedepentent.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My expectation is that repeatedly opening, writing to, then closing, a file should cause lines to be written in the same order as they appear in the code. Obviously I'm missing something. (I have now added OS info to the post.)

Comment: Put the expectation in the question please.

Comment: Re "*Obviously I'm missing something.*" That fact that you aren't closing until the very end.

Comment: Worth noting is that the same effect also occurs when using 'if' instead of 'for'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just a complicated version of

```perl
open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt");
print $fh "one\n";
open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt");
print $fh "two\n";
open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt");
print $fh "three\n";
```

Let's make small change to make things more readable and easier to discuss:

```perl
open(my $fh1, ">>", "test.txt");
print $fh1 "one\n";
open(my $fh2, ">>", "test.txt");
print $fh2 "two\n";
open(my $fh3, ">>", "test.txt");
print $fh3 "three\n";
```

This is equivalent because each `my` creates a new variable.

So what's happening?

```perl
open(my $fh1, ">>", "test.txt");  # You create a file handle.
print $fh1 "one\n";               # You write to the file handle's buffer.
open(my $fh2, ">>", "test.txt");  # You create a file handle.
print $fh2 "two\n";               # You write to the file handle's buffer.
open(my $fh3, ">>", "test.txt");  # You create a file handle.
print $fh3 "three\n";             # You write to the file handle's buffer.
# Implicit close($fh3);           # You close the file handle, flushing its buffer.
# Implicit close($fh2);           # You close the file handle, flushing its buffer.
# Implicit close($fh1);           # You close the file handle, flushing its buffer.
```

Since Perl doesn't guarantee the order in which variable are destroyed, you could easily get the output in any order.

The solution is to flush the handles after printing to them (`$fh->flush;`, or `$fh->autoflush(1);`), or close the handles earlier.

```perl
{ open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt");  print $fh "one\n";   }
{ open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt");  print $fh "two\n";   }
{ open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt");  print $fh "three\n"; }
```

Comment: Can you add a reason as to why the handle isn't flushed and the variable destroyed at the end of each `for()` loop? Also, why doesn't `$|=1` work?

Comment: Re "*why doesn't $|=1 work?*", `$| = 1;` does work if you select the correct handle. Remember, `$| = 1;` sets autoflushing for *the currently selected handle*.

Comment: Re "*Can you add a reason why the handle isn'[...] destroyed at the end of each for() loop?*", Scopes are traditionally formed by curlies.

Comment: Of course. I totally overlooked that in the OP, that the `open` isn't actually within the `for()` block itself.

Comment: Yeah. The tricky bit, though, is that the scope for the purpose of variable visibility and the scope for the purpose of variable existence aren't quite the same. The latter is determined by curlies. The former is a bit tighter sometimes (like here).

Comment: @ikegami But if $fh is still in scope, then why does `for(open(my $fh, ">>", "test.txt")){ print $fh "aaa\n"; } print $fh "bbb\n";`  fail with "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference"?

Comment: See previous comment :)

Comment: I'm also psychic.

Answer (score 3):

As already explained by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami), the reason for this behaviour lies in the different scopes of variable visibility and existence.
Here is a small example visualizing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.16;
use warnings;
use experimental 'signatures';

package MyScalar;

sub TIESCALAR ($class, $val) {
    my $self = \$val;
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub FETCH ($self) {
    $$self;
}

sub DESTROY ($self) {
    warn "destroying $$self\n";
}


package main;

for (tie my $val, 'MyScalar', 'first') {
    say $val;
}
for (tie my $val, 'MyScalar', 'second') {
    say $val;
}
for (tie my $val, 'MyScalar', 'third') {
    say $val;
}
```

The variables are destroyed in an unpredictable order. Here the output is:

```
destroying second
destroying first
destroying third
first
second
third
```